# Angular 2 lagging when click on screen

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire2

I'm new to Angular 2. First, when my website has a little bit of data(15 items-post on page by using ngFor) it works normally. But when items reach around 35 items, lagging problem occurred when I click on the screen.

I have searched about this problem I found that it may be caused by every child and parent are listening the event all the time. I also found that Ticks is high when I was clicking.

I have tried `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`but it didn't help.
I also recorded my website performance and I got this [Test results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHS5g.jpg)

Anyone know how to solve this problem ? I have been working on it so hard, but also can't fix it.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from "rxjs/Subject";
import { CurrentUserService } from "app/service/current-user/current-user.service";
import { FirebaseListObservable, AngularFire, FirebaseObjectObservable } from "angularfire2";
import { SendKeyService } from '../../service/send-key/send-key.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../../service/auth/auth.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { SendArticleKeyService } from "app/service/send-article-key/send-article-key.service";
import { CommentTxt } from "app/home-page/shared/comment.model";
import { ReplyTxt } from "app/profile-page/shared/reply.model";
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

import { Comment } from '../shared/comment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile-list',
  templateUrl: './profile-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile-list.component.css']
})

export class ProfileListComponent implements OnInit {
  currentUser: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
  items: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
  items2: Observable<any>;
  likecount: Observable<any>;
  countlike: Observable<any>;
  private uid: String;
  profileid: string;
  user: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;

  comments: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
  users: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
  replies: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

  @Output() commentSubmit: EventEmitter<CommentTxt> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() replySubmit: EventEmitter<ReplyTxt> = new EventEmitter();
  public comment:CommentTxt
  public reply:ReplyTxt
  public psid: string;
  snapshot1: Array<any>;

  checklike: boolean = false;
  liketext: string;
  setlike: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

  checklike2 = []

  checklikecomment: boolean = false;
  checkcommentlike = [];


  checkreplylike = [];
  checklikereply: boolean = false;
  userpost = [];
  viewlike = [];

  postlist = [];

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, public af: AngularFire, 
              public userService: CurrentUserService, public sendKey: SendKeyService, 
              public router: Router, public sendArticleKey : SendArticleKeyService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {

      this.setProfile();
      this.authService.af.auth.subscribe(
      (auth) => {
        if(auth == null){

        }
        else {
          this.uid = auth.auth.uid;
          this.currentUser = af.database.object('user-info/' + this.uid);
          //this.items = af.database.list('posts')
          this.items2 = af.database.list('post');
          /*this.items.subscribe(data => {
            data.forEach(snap => {
              this.likecount = af.database.list('post-likes/' + snap.$key);
              this.likecount.subscribe(data2 => {
               //this.countlike = data2.length
                //console.log(data2.length)
                const likelist = Observable.from(data2)
                  
                  const res = likelist.subscribe({
                    next(value) {console.log(value)},
                    error(error) {console.log(error)},
                    complete() {console.log('complete')}
                    
                  })
                  
                  const output =  likelist.switch()
                  this.countlike = output['source']['array'].length.toString()
                  console.log('postkey: ' + snap.$key + ' likecount: ' + this.countlike)
              })
              
              //console.log(val))
            })
          })*/
          
          // query user-post //
          /*var items = firebase.database().ref().child('user-post').child(this.profileid).on("value", snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
              let item = childSnapshot.val();
              item['key'] = childSnapshot.key;
              //array.push(ite);
               const postlist = firebase.database().ref().child('posts').child(item['key']).on("value" , snapshot2 => {
                 //console.log(snapshot2.val())
                 this.snapshot1.push(snapshot2.val());
               })
              return false;
            })
            return true;
          });
          console.log(this.snapshot1);*/
          this.users = af.database.list('user-info/')
          this.comments = af.database.list('comment');
          this.replies = af.database.list('reply');
          
          
        }
      }
    )

    
    this.resetComment();
    this.resetReply();
  }

  clicklike(key, index, check){
    this.checklike = true;
    const postlike = firebase.database().ref().child('post-like').child(key).child(this.uid.toString()).once("value", snapshot => {
      if(this.checklike == true){
        if(snapshot.val() != null){
          const ref = this.af.database.list('post-like/' + key);
          ref.remove(this.uid.toString())

          const ref2 = this.af.database.object('post/' + key + '/likePostCount');
          ref2.$ref.transaction(likePostCount => {
            return likePostCount - 1
          })

          const ref3 = this.af.database.object('user-post/' + this.profileid + '/' + key + '/likePostCount')
          ref3.$ref.transaction(likePostCount => {
            return likePostCount - 1
          })

          const ref4 = this.af.database.object('post-rating/' + this.profileid + '/' + key + '/likePostCount')
          ref4.$ref.transaction(likePostCount => {
            return likePostCount - 1
          })
          this.checklike2[index].checklike = !check;

        }
        else{
          const ref = this.af.database.object('post-like/' + key);
          ref.$ref.child(this.uid.toString()).set(true);

          const ref2 = this.af.database.object('post/' + key + '/likePostCount');

          ref2.$ref.transaction(likePostCount => {
            return likePostCount + 1
          })

          const ref3 = this.af.database.object('user-post/' + this.profileid + '/' + key + '/likePostCount')
          ref3.$ref.transaction(likePostCount => {
            return likePostCount + 1
          })

          const ref4 = this.af.database.object('post-rating/' + this.profileid + '/' + key + '/likePostCount')
          ref4.$ref.transaction(likePostCount => {
            return likePostCount + 1
          })
          this.checklike2[index].checklike = !check;
        }
      
      }
    })
    
     
   }

   private getComment(){
     this.snapshot1 = [];
     const comment = firebase.database().ref().child('user-post').child(this.profileid).on("value", snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
              let item = childSnapshot.val();
              item['key'] = childSnapshot.key;
              const commentlist = firebase.database().ref().child('post-comment').child(item['key']).on("value", snapshot2 => {
                
                snapshot2.forEach((childSnapshot2) => {
                  const fetchcomment = firebase.database().ref().child('comment').child(childSnapshot2.key).on("value", snapshot3 => {
                    //console.log(snapshot3.val())
                    this.snapshot1.push(new Comment(snapshot3.val().textComment, snapshot3.val().postkey, snapshot3.val().likeCommentCount, snapshot3.val().ownerComment, 
                    snapshot3.val().replyCommentCount,snapshot3.val().timestamp))
                    //console.log(this.snapshot1)
                  })
                  return false;
                })
                //this.snapshot1.pop()
              })
              return true;
            })
           // this.snapshot1 = this.snapshot1["0"]
           
          })
   }

   private setProfile() {
    /*const { id } = this.route.snapshot.params;
    this.profileid = id;
    this.user = this.af.database.object('users/' + id);*/
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      let id = params['id'];
      this.profileid = id;
      this.user = this.af.database.object('user/' + id);
      this.items = this.af.database.list('user-post/' + this.profileid);
      this.checklikes(id)
      // const userlike = this.af.database.list('user-posts/' + this.profileid).subscribe(val => {
      //       this.checklike2 = [];
      //       val.forEach(snapshot => {
      //         this.checklike2.push({key: snapshot.$key, value: false})
      //         const checklike = firebase.database().ref().child('post-likes').child(snapshot.$key).on("value", snapshot2 => {
      //           snapshot2.forEach(childSnap => {
      //             //var eiei = Object.keys(snapshot.val())
      //             if(childSnap.key == this.uid){
      //               this.checklike2.pop()
      //               this.checklike2.push({key : snapshot.$key, value: true})
      //             }
      //             return false;
      //           })
      //         })
      //       })
      //     })
      
    })
    
    
  }

  // @HostListener('window:scroll') onScroll() {
  //   // let pos = (document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop) + document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
  //   let pos = (document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop)
  //   let max = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
    
  //   // console.log('pos', pos)
  //   // console.log('max', max)
  //   // if(pos == (max))   {
  //   //   console.log('eiei')
  //   // }
  // }

  checklikes(id){
    return firebase.database().ref(`/user-post/${id}`).once("value", snap =>{
        if(snap.val() != null){
          const post_keys = Object.keys(snap.val())
          this.checklike2 = [];
          this.checkcommentlike = [];
          post_keys.forEach(key => {
              const checklike = firebase.database().ref(`/post-like/${key}`).orderByKey().equalTo(this.uid.toString()).once("value" , likesnap => {
                if(likesnap.hasChildren()){
                  var post = Object.assign({checklike: true, $key: key})
                  this.checklike2.push(post)
                }
                else{
                  var post = Object.assign({checklike: false, $key: key})
                  this.checklike2.push(post)
                }
              })

              const checkcommentlike = firebase.database().ref(`/post-comment/${key}`).once("value", snaplike => {
                if(snaplike.val() != null){
                  const comment_keys = Object.keys(snaplike.val())
                  comment_keys.forEach(commentkey => {
                    const checkcommentlike = firebase.database().ref(`/comment-like/${commentkey}`).orderByKey().equalTo(this.uid.toString()).once("value", likesnap => {
                      if(likesnap.hasChildren()){
                        var comment = Object.assign({checkcomlike: true, $key: commentkey})
                        this.checkcommentlike.push(comment)
                      }
                      else {
                        var comment = Object.assign({checkcomlike: false, $key: commentkey})
                        this.checkcommentlike.push(comment)
                      }
                    })

                    const checkreplylike = firebase.database().ref(`/comment-reply/${commentkey}`).once("value", snap => {
                      if(snap.val() != null) {
                        const reply_keys = Object.keys(snap.val())
                        reply_keys.forEach(replykey => {
                          const checkreplylike = firebase.database().ref(`/reply-like/${replykey}`).orderByKey().equalTo(this.uid.toString()).once("value", snaprep => {
                            if(snaprep.hasChildren()){
                              var reply = Object.assign({checkreplike: true, $key: replykey})
                              this.checkreplylike.push(reply)
                            }
                            else {
                              var reply = Object.assign({checkreplike: false, $key: replykey})
                              this.checkreplylike.push(reply)
                            }
                          })
                        })
                      }
                    })
                  })
                }
              })
          })
        }
        
        
      })
  }

  likecomment(commentkey, index, check){

    this.checklikecomment = true;
    const commentlike = firebase.database().ref().child('comment-like').child(commentkey).child(this.uid.toString()).once("value", snapshot => {
      if(this.checklikecomment == true){
        if(snapshot.val() != null){
          const ref = this.af.database.list('comment-like/' + commentkey);
          ref.remove(this.uid.toString())

          const ref2 = firebase.database().ref().child('comment').child(commentkey).child('likeCommentCount')

          ref2.transaction(likeCommentCount => {
            return likeCommentCount - 1
          })
          this.checkcommentlike[index].checkcomlike = !check;
        }
        else{
          const ref = this.af.database.object('comment-like/' + commentkey);
          ref.$ref.child(this.uid.toString()).set(true);

          const ref2 = firebase.database().ref().child('comment').child(commentkey).child('likeCommentCount')

          ref2.transaction(likeCommentCount => {
            return likeCommentCount + 1
          })
          this.checkcommentlike[index].checkcomlike = !check;
        }
      
      }
    })
  }

  likereply(replykey, index, check){
    this.checklikereply = true;
    const replylike = firebase.database().ref().child('reply-like').child(replykey).child(this.uid.toString()).once("value", snapshot => {
      if(this.checklikereply == true){
        if(snapshot.val() != null){
          const ref = this.af.database.list('reply-like/' + replykey);
          ref.remove(this.uid.toString())

          const ref2 = firebase.database().ref().child('reply').child(replykey).child('likeReplyCount')

          ref2.transaction(likeReplyCount => {
            return likeReplyCount - 1
          })
          this.checkreplylike[index].checkreplike = !check;
        }
        else{
          const ref = this.af.database.object('reply-like/' + replykey);
          ref.$ref.child(this.uid.toString()).set(true);

          const ref2 = firebase.database().ref().child('reply').child(replykey).child('likeReplyCount')

          ref2.transaction(likeReplyCount => {
            return likeReplyCount + 1
          })
          this.checkreplylike[index].checkreplike = !check;
        }
      
      }
    })
  }

  viewlikes(key){
    this.viewlike = [];
    const ref = firebase.database().ref().child('post-like').child(key).once("value", val => {
      var likeview = Object.keys(val.val())
      likeview.forEach(key => {
        this.viewlike.push({$key: key})
      })
    })
    
  }

  commentText(comment: string, pid: string, event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
      this.comment.commentText = comment;
      this.comment.postKey = pid;
      this.commentSubmit.emit(this.comment);
      this.resetComment();
    }
    
  }

  commentText2(comment: string, pid: string, event, owner){
      this.comment.commentText = comment;
      this.comment.postKey = pid;
      this.comment.ownerPost = owner;
      this.commentSubmit.emit(this.comment);
      this.resetComment();
      
  }

  replyText(commentkey: string, reply: string, postkey: string){
    this.reply.replyText = reply;
    this.reply.commentKey = commentkey;
    this.reply.postKey = postkey;
    this.replySubmit.emit(this.reply);
  }

  sharePost(postkey: string, caption: string, owner: string){
    /* write to share-post*/
    /*const sharepost = this.af.database.list('share-posts');
    this.psid = sharepost.push({
      sharepostkey: postkey
    }).key*/

    const ref = this.af.database.object('post-share/' + postkey)
    ref.$ref.child(this.uid.toString()).set(true)
    /* write to posts*/
    if(caption != null){
      const sharepost2 = this.af.database.list('post/');
      this.psid = sharepost2.push({
        ownerPost: this.uid,
        typePost: "share",
        timestamp: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
        sharePostKey: postkey,
        likePostCount: 0,
        sharePostCount: 0,
        textPost: caption,
        commentPostCount: 0,
        statusPost: "normal"
      }).key
      /* write to user-post*/
      const sharepost3 = this.af.database.object('user-post/' + this.uid + '/' + this.psid);
      sharepost3.update({
        ownerPost: this.uid,
        typePost: "share",
        timestamp: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
        sharePostKey: postkey,
        textPost: caption,
        likePostCount: 0,
        commentPostCount: 0,
        statusPost: "normal"
      })

      const sharepost4 = this.af.database.object('post-rating/' + this.uid + '/' + this.psid);
      sharepost4.update({
        timestamp: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
        sharePostCount: 0,
        likePostCount: 0,
        commentPostCount: 0,
        statusPost: "normal"
      })
    }
    else {
       const sharepost2 = this.af.database.list('post/');
      sharepost2.push({
        ownerPost: this.uid,
        typePost: "share",
        timestamp: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
        sharePostKey: postkey,
        likePostCount: 0,
        sharePostCount: 0,
        textPost: '',
        commentPostCount: 0,
        statusPost: "normal"
      })
      /* write to user-post*/
      const sharepost3 = this.af.database.object('user-post/' + this.uid + '/' + this.psid);
      sharepost3.update({
        ownerPost: this.uid,
        typePost: "share",
        timestamp: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
        sharePostKey: postkey,
        textPost: '',
        likePostCount: 0,
        commentPostCount: 0,
        statusPost: "normal"
      })

      const sharepost4 = this.af.database.object('post-rating/' + this.uid + '/' + this.psid);
      sharepost4.update({
        timestamp: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
        sharePostCount: 0,
        likePostCount: 0,
        commentPostCount: 0,
        statusPost: "normal"
      })
    }
    /* update sharecount*/
    // const sharecount = this.af.database.object('post/' + postkey);
    // var countshared:number;
    // sharecount.subscribe(val => {
    //    countshared = val.sharePostCount + 1
    // })
    // sharecount.update({
    //   sharePostCount: countshared
    // })

    const sharecount = firebase.database().ref().child('post').child(postkey).child('sharePostCount')

    sharecount.transaction(sharePostCount => {
      return sharePostCount + 1
    })

    const sharecount2 = firebase.database().ref().child('user-post').child(owner).child(postkey).child('sharePostCount')

    sharecount2.transaction(sharePostCount => {
      return sharePostCount + 1
    })

    const sharecount3 = firebase.database().ref().child('post-rating').child(owner).child(postkey).child('sharePostCount')

    sharecount3.transaction(sharePostCount => {
      return sharePostCount + 1
    })
  }

  deleteItem(key: string) {
    const firstref = this.af.database.list('post/')
    firstref.remove(key);
    
    const ref = this.af.database.list('post-like/', {
      query:{
        orderByKey: true,
        equalTo: key
      }
    });
    ref.remove(key);

    const ref2 = this.af.database.list('user-post/' + this.uid)
    ref2.remove(key);
    
    const ref3 = this.af.database.list('post-share/')
    ref3.remove(key);

    const ref4 = this.af.database.list('post-comment/')
    ref4.remove(key);

    const ref5 = this.af.database.list('comment/')
    ref5.subscribe(val => {
      val.forEach(comment => {
        if(comment.postkey == key){
          const deletecomment = firebase.database().ref().child('comment/').child(comment.$key)
          deletecomment.remove(key.toString)
        }
        
      })
    })

    const ref6 = this.af.database.list('post-rating/' + this.uid)
    ref6.remove(key);

    // const deleteitem = this.af.database.list('newfeed/').subscribe(val => {
    //   val.forEach(snapshot => {
    //     const ref6 = this.af.database.list('newfeed/' + snapshot.$key)
    //     ref6.remove(key)
    //   })
    // })
  }

   /*send_ArticleKey(key){
    this.sendArticleKey.saveData(key); 
    this.router.navigate(['article-view/' + key]);
   }*/
   updateItem(key: string, newText: string) {
    this.items.update(key, { textPost: newText });
  }

  deleteComment(commentkey: string, postkey: string, ownercomment:string){
    const ref = this.af.database.list('comment/')
    ref.remove(commentkey)

    const ref2 = this.af.database.list('post-comment/' + postkey)
    ref2.remove(commentkey)

    const ref3 = firebase.database().ref().child('post').child(postkey).child('commentPostCount')

    ref3.transaction(commentPostCount => {
      return commentPostCount - 1
    })

    const ref4 = firebase.database().ref().child('user-post').child(ownercomment).child(postkey).child('commentPostCount')

    ref4.transaction(commentPostCount => {
      return commentPostCount - 1
    })

    const ref5 = firebase.database().ref().child('post-rating').child(ownercomment).child(postkey).child('commentPostCount')

    ref5.transaction(commentPostCount => {
      return commentPostCount - 1
    })
  }

  updateComment(commentkey: string, text: string){
    const ref = this.af.database.object('comment/' + commentkey)
    ref.update({
      textComment: text
    })
  }

  updateview(postkey: string, owner: string){
    const postview = firebase.database().ref().child('post-view').child(postkey).child(this.uid.toString()).once("value", snapshot => {
      if(snapshot.val() == null){
        const ref = this.af.database.object('post-view/' + postkey);
        ref.$ref.child(this.uid.toString()).set(true)
        
        const ref2 = firebase.database().ref().child('post').child(postkey).child('viewPostCount')
        ref2.transaction(viewPostCount => {
          return viewPostCount + 1
        })

        const ref3 = firebase.database().ref().child('user-post').child(owner).child(postkey).child('viewPostCount')
        ref3.transaction(viewPostCount => {
          return viewPostCount + 1
        })

        const ref4 = firebase.database().ref().child('post-rating').child(owner).child(postkey).child('viewPostCount')
        ref4.transaction(viewPostCount => {
          return viewPostCount + 1
        })
      }
    })
    
    
  }

  autogrow(){
    let  textArea = document.getElementById("textarea")       
    textArea.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    textArea.style.height = '0px';
    textArea.style.height = textArea.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }

  private resetComment(){
    this.comment = new CommentTxt();
  }

  private resetReply(){
    this.reply = new ReplyTxt();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    //this.getComment();
    
  }

  

}
```

Comment: Can you share more about your code, components , events ... ?

Comment: Maybe an evil extension, try running in incognito mode.

Comment: @ThienHoang I shared it already. Do you have any suggestion ?